# How to install curl 7.34 or later on Amazon linux old instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, curl, amazon-linux

We are using a few older instances to run our server at work, and since they are already in sunset mode we dont really want to update the AMIs. However we now need curl that is able to use TLS 1.2 and that means 7.34 or later. `yum` lists 7.27 as the latest on our instance, coming from `amzn-updates` repo. What are our options to update curl on these machines? The openssl version on these machines does support TLS1.2, it is only `curl` that doesnt support it. Specifically we need `git` to support TLS1.2.

Comment: One option seems to be the `city-fan` repo found in other answers, which is warned against by redhat.

Comment: Another option is to install from source I guess.

Comment: Are there any other options?